# Spindle diameter on the FSA Gossamer TT MegaExo crankset

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, compatibility

What is the spindle diameter on the FSA Gossamer TT MegaExo crankset? 24 mm or 30 mm? I can't find a direct answer anywhere. I have seen MegaExo described as 19 or 24 mm, but "Gossamer" as 30. I'm looking at the aforementioned crankset for my Giant Trinity BB90 bottom bracket shell, but I don't want to go 30 mm.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Gossamer is more of a ‘level’ of FSA products rather than a particular crank model.

*MegaExo* is an FSS external bearing bottom bracket type for BSA threaded shells. It uses a 24mm spindle diameter.

According to [this article](https://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/)  24mm spindle external bearing road cranks are compatible with BB90.

Comment: Maybe contact FSA and ask what they have that is compatible with BB90?

Comment: I believe the diameter  of MegaExo spindle is 24.05mm, which is why a grease and rubber mallet is required if you insert a MegaExo crank into a Shimano bottom bracket, which is a true 24.00mm.

Comment: @Rider_X personally have a SLK MegaExo in a Shimano external bearing BB and it is indeed a bit tight.